# Putting pandas dataframes into excel with python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, openpyxl

I have a few dataframes that I am trying to transfer to excel.

Using this method, I successfully did so...

```
writer = ExcelWriter(f'DRAGON{date}.xlsx')
stats.to_excel(writer, f'ELO{date}')
pdf.to_excel(writer, f'Playoffs{date}')
sec.to_excel(writer, f'Second Round{date}')
cf.to_excel(writer, f'Conference Finals{date}')
cham.to_excel(writer, f'Finals{date}')
df.to_excel(writer, f'Stanley Cup Winner{date}')

writer.save()
writer.close()
```

This worked for a while, but for some reason it stopped working the other day and I kept getting this error

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'write'

and this

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openpyxl'

I have no idea what is going on, especially because I have installed openpyxl using pip.

If anyone has any clue, let me know

Here is the code from the actual writer

```
import pandas._libs.json as json
import openpyxl

from pandas.io.excel._base import ExcelWriter
from pandas.io.excel._util import _validate_freeze_panes


class _XlsxStyler:
    # Map from openpyxl-oriented styles to flatter xlsxwriter representation
    # Ordering necessary for both determinism and because some are keyed by
    # prefixes of others.
    STYLE_MAPPING = {
        "font": [
            (("name",), "font_name"),
            (("sz",), "font_size"),
            (("size",), "font_size"),
            (("color", "rgb"), "font_color"),
            (("color",), "font_color"),
            (("b",), "bold"),
            (("bold",), "bold"),
            (("i",), "italic"),
            (("italic",), "italic"),
            (("u",), "underline"),
            (("underline",), "underline"),
            (("strike",), "font_strikeout"),
            (("vertAlign",), "font_script"),
            (("vertalign",), "font_script"),
        ],
        "number_format": [(("format_code",), "num_format"), ((), "num_format")],
        "protection": [(("locked",), "locked"), (("hidden",), "hidden")],
        "alignment": [
            (("horizontal",), "align"),
            (("vertical",), "valign"),
            (("text_rotation",), "rotation"),
            (("wrap_text",), "text_wrap"),
            (("indent",), "indent"),
            (("shrink_to_fit",), "shrink"),
        ],
        "fill": [
            (("patternType",), "pattern"),
            (("patterntype",), "pattern"),
            (("fill_type",), "pattern"),
            (("start_color", "rgb"), "fg_color"),
            (("fgColor", "rgb"), "fg_color"),
            (("fgcolor", "rgb"), "fg_color"),
            (("start_color",), "fg_color"),
            (("fgColor",), "fg_color"),
            (("fgcolor",), "fg_color"),
            (("end_color", "rgb"), "bg_color"),
            (("bgColor", "rgb"), "bg_color"),
            (("bgcolor", "rgb"), "bg_color"),
            (("end_color",), "bg_color"),
            (("bgColor",), "bg_color"),
            (("bgcolor",), "bg_color"),
        ],
        "border": [
            (("color", "rgb"), "border_color"),
            (("color",), "border_color"),
            (("style",), "border"),
            (("top", "color", "rgb"), "top_color"),
            (("top", "color"), "top_color"),
            (("top", "style"), "top"),
            (("top",), "top"),
            (("right", "color", "rgb"), "right_color"),
            (("right", "color"), "right_color"),
            (("right", "style"), "right"),
            (("right",), "right"),
            (("bottom", "color", "rgb"), "bottom_color"),
            (("bottom", "color"), "bottom_color"),
            (("bottom", "style"), "bottom"),
            (("bottom",), "bottom"),
            (("left", "color", "rgb"), "left_color"),
            (("left", "color"), "left_color"),
            (("left", "style"), "left"),
            (("left",), "left"),
        ],
    }

    @classmethod
    def convert(cls, style_dict, num_format_str=None):
        """
        converts a style_dict to an xlsxwriter format dict

        Parameters
        ----------
        style_dict : style dictionary to convert
        num_format_str : optional number format string
        """

        # Create a XlsxWriter format object.
        props = {}

        if num_format_str is not None:
            props["num_format"] = num_format_str

        if style_dict is None:
            return props

        if "borders" in style_dict:
            style_dict = style_dict.copy()
            style_dict["border"] = style_dict.pop("borders")

        for style_group_key, style_group in style_dict.items():
            for src, dst in cls.STYLE_MAPPING.get(style_group_key, []):
                # src is a sequence of keys into a nested dict
                # dst is a flat key
                if dst in props:
                    continue
                v = style_group
                for k in src:
                    try:
                        v = v[k]
                    except (KeyError, TypeError):
                        break
                else:
                    props[dst] = v

        if isinstance(props.get("pattern"), str):
            # TODO: support other fill patterns
            props["pattern"] = 0 if props["pattern"] == "none" else 1

        for k in ["border", "top", "right", "bottom", "left"]:
            if isinstance(props.get(k), str):
                try:
                    props[k] = [
                        "none",
                        "thin",
                        "medium",
                        "dashed",
                        "dotted",
                        "thick",
                        "double",
                        "hair",
                        "mediumDashed",
                        "dashDot",
                        "mediumDashDot",
                        "dashDotDot",
                        "mediumDashDotDot",
                        "slantDashDot",
                    ].index(props[k])
                except ValueError:
                    props[k] = 2

        if isinstance(props.get("font_script"), str):
            props["font_script"] = ["baseline", "superscript", "subscript"].index(
                props["font_script"]
            )

        if isinstance(props.get("underline"), str):
            props["underline"] = {
                "none": 0,
                "single": 1,
                "double": 2,
                "singleAccounting": 33,
                "doubleAccounting": 34,
            }[props["underline"]]

        return props


class _XlsxWriter(ExcelWriter):
    engine = "xlsxwriter"
    supported_extensions = (".xlsx",)

    def __init__(
        self,
        path,
        engine=None,
        date_format=None,
        datetime_format=None,
        mode="w",
        **engine_kwargs,
    ):
        # Use the xlsxwriter module as the Excel writer.
        import xlsxwriter

        if mode == "a":
            raise ValueError("Append mode is not supported with xlsxwriter!")

        super().__init__(
            path,
            engine=engine,
            date_format=date_format,
            datetime_format=datetime_format,
            mode=mode,
            **engine_kwargs,
        )

        self.book = xlsxwriter.Workbook(path, **engine_kwargs)

    def save(self):
        """
        Save workbook to disk.
        """

        return self.book.close()

    def write_cells(
        self, cells, sheet_name=None, startrow=0, startcol=0, freeze_panes=None
    ):
        # Write the frame cells using xlsxwriter.
        sheet_name = self._get_sheet_name(sheet_name)

        if sheet_name in self.sheets:
            wks = self.sheets[sheet_name]
        else:
            wks = 0
            self.sheets[sheet_name] = wks

        style_dict = {"null": None}

        if _validate_freeze_panes(freeze_panes):
            wks.freeze_panes(*(freeze_panes))

        for cell in cells:
            val, fmt = self._value_with_fmt(cell.val)

            stylekey = json.dumps(cell.style)
            if fmt:
                stylekey += fmt

            if stylekey in style_dict:
                style = style_dict[stylekey]
            else:
                style = self.book.add_format(_XlsxStyler.convert(cell.style, fmt))
                style_dict[stylekey] = style

            if cell.mergestart is not None and cell.mergeend is not None:
                wks.merge_range(
                    startrow + cell.row,
                    startcol + cell.col,
                    startrow + cell.mergestart,
                    startcol + cell.mergeend,
                    val,
                    style,
                )
            else:
                wks.write(startrow + cell.row, startcol + cell.col, val, style)
```

Comment: Please post all code from the actual writer.

Comment: okay, I just updated

Comment: Are you using multiple enviornments? or did you install a new version of python recently?

Comment: @AhsanGoheer I am using python 3.8 with spyder...I downloaded openpyxl with the command prompt without creating a virtualenv, but then when I got this error I indexed into the folder it said the program was running in and tried downloading openpyxl again but it said it was already installed so I am not sure what the issue is,

Comment: I had a similar issue a while back. It was due to the fact that I had two installations of python on my system. Other than spyder, did you ever install python separately on your system? Also, this might seem like an obvious question but did you use the anaconda command prompt to install openpyxl?

Comment: I used the windows command prompt...should I do that differently? Also yes, I recently installed python through another application

Comment: That's your problem then. Basically, your second installation is the default one for your system not the spyder one. So when you install openpyxl using CMD you're installing it for your second python installation. Try using the anaconda prompt to install openpyxl or run your code using windows command prompt.

Comment: What if I were to uninstall the other version?

Comment: You would need to add the path of the Spyder python installation in your environment variables if it's not already added. But yes that could work.